# Can't run wine using crontab?

Tags: cron, wine

My crontab:

```
* * * * * ~/d2gs.sh
```

My application:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# D2GS
#

# Go to the directory
cd ~

# Run the applications
if ! ps aux | pgrep "D2GS"; then
    wine "C:/D2GS/D2GS.exe" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

The crontab is not starting the process. Which is weird, since I can run ~/d2gs.sh successfully manually.

Comment: What does the generated mail message say?

Comment: `cron` does not set any of your environment variables. Probably relevant:  https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: This is your second question about the same script.  What is the _actual_ problem you're trying to solve with it?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I want to thank you for the reply in the first question - the `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` worked. But now, the crontab doesn't fire the `d2gs.sh`. I can start it only using the terminal. Crontab doesn't start it...

Comment: What is your `D2GS.exe` program really doing? Why are you using Linux to start a Windows program?

Comment: Why do you use `wine` ? It is generally considered not mature enough... Can't you adopt a Linux mindset and use *only* Linux programs? Or use Windows (and perhaps some VM running Linux, or vice versa)

Comment: http://pvpgn.wikia.com/wiki/D2GS_Server

Comment: I'm using wine to start a Windows program, since there's no Linux version of it. And it's connected to a Linux program, so I have no other choice.

Comment: But it could happen that your `wine` cannot handle that precise Windows program. Some Windows programs don't work on `wine`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish between "the crontab is not starting the process" and "the process does start but does not do what it is supposed to". And make sure the file is executable.

In contrast to what I assumed the usage of `~` in `crontab` is not a problem. The whole command string is passed to a shell.

Comment: I am not sure that `/bin/sh` is *required* to expand `~` even if *some* implementations of it could understand that expansion.

Comment: With the full path or not, it still doesn't start. I've saw somewhere, that I need to specify `export DISPLAY=:0`, but I don't have X-server on my server.

Comment: @htorbov You may need an X Window virtual framebuffer (Xvfb)

Answer (score 1):

The `cd ~` might not work (since [tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) is not universal). Prefer `cd $HOME` to it (which is guaranteed to do the same for all implementations of `/bin/sh` ...) ..... Remember that POSIX `sh` (or `/bin/sh`) is generally *not* `bash` (and your `/bin/sh` might not be fully POSIX compliant, but more "bourne"-like)!

Of course, you could add something like `pwd > /dev/stderr` in your script (for debugging purposes).

`wine` generally needs an [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server to display windows. And a program started from `cron` generally don't any X11 server or terminal. So `wine` is probably failing to start (from your `cron` job). You might need to set some `DISPLAY`  variable for [Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib). But you might use Xvfb, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36608933/841108).

At last, [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) is scanning processes. Either use `ps aux | grep "D2GS"` or learn how to use `pgrep`  alone.

I recommend using `echo something > /dev/stderr` or better `echo` or [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) (with a suitable [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing))) or [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) in your script, at least for debugging purposes (in several places).

And I won't redirect `wine`-s stderr and stdout to `/dev/null` at least during the debugging phase. Can't you code (at least *temporarily* during debugging) 
 `wine "C:/D2GS/D2GS.exe" >> /tmp/wine.out 2>&1` and look into `/tmp/wine.out`  with some pager like `less` ?

Your `cron` (and your shell script) is not using your interactive [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). You should consider setting it *explicitly* in your script (or `crontab`). See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).

Comment: The first part makes no sense. The question says that the script works when called manually. Also, it's easy enough to test that `~` *does* work in a `sh` script.

Comment: I am not sure that the OP's shell is working like `cron`. It probably does not. And `cd $HOME` is certainly more `sh` friendly than `cd ~` (which is probably a bashism)

Comment: With the full path or not, it still doesn't start. I've saw somewhere, that I need to specify `export DISPLAY=:0`, but I don't have X-server on my server.

Comment: Then you cannot use `wine`  for `D2GS.exe`; BTW the X11 server might run on some other machine (and screen). But you probably need one.